# Linear transformation $S$ with $S\circ S=S$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I need help with the next problem. Really I don't know how can I solve it. The problem is the next:

> Let $S:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a linear
>   transformation such that $S\circ S=S$. Proof the next sentences.
>
> a) $S=0$, i.e., the zero transformation.
>
> b) $S=1_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}$, i.e., the identity transformation.
>
> c) Exist $\beta$ basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that
>
> $$ [S]_{\beta}^{\beta} = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \\
>  \end{array} \right) $$

For the b), I thought the next

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Then, $S(x)=v$ with $v\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Using the hypothesis, then $S(v)=S(S(x))=S(x)=v$. Hence, $S(v)=v$. Therefore, $S$ is the identity transformation.

Comment: A linear transformation such that $T^2 = T$ is known as a [projection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProjectionMatrix.html)

Comment: Your proof that the operator is identity is wrong. You said S(v) = v. But, this does not hold for any general v, as v belongs to range(S) as you assume v = S(x). In general, T need not be the identity or null operator. The identity and zero operator are special cases.

Comment: The way you wrote is confusing: all three claims (a), (b), (c) are false, so **what** exactly is that you have to do?  To refute them with examples or what?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is the solution:

If $Ker(S)=\{\bar{0}\}$, then, $Im(S)=\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Now, let $x\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Then, $S(x)=v$ with $v\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Using the hypothesis, $S(v)=S(S(x))=S(x)=v$. Hence, $S(v)=v$ for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ Therefore, $S$ is the identity transformation.

If $Im(S)=\{\bar{0}\}$, then clearly $S$ is the zero transformation.

If $Im(S)\neq\{\bar{0}\}$ and $Ker(S)\neq\{\bar{0}\}$, i.e., the $Kernel$ and the $Image$ of $S$ are not trivial. Like $S\circ S=S$, then $S$ is a projection. One of the properties of a projection (in this particular case) is the next: $$\mathbb{R}^{2}=Ker(S)\bigoplus Im(S)$$Take $r\in Im(S)$ and $u\in Ker(S)$ such that $r\neq\bar{0}$ and $u\neq\bar{0}$. We claim that the set $\{r,u\}$ is linearly independent

(The proof is by contradiction. Suppose that $\{r,u\}$ is not linearly independent, then, $r=\lambda_0 u$ with $\lambda_0 \in\mathbb{R}$). But, $r\in Im(S)$ and $u\in Ker(S)$ and by the fact of $Ker(S)$ is subspace, then $(\lambda_0 u=r)\in Ker(S)$. Hence, $r\in Ker(S)\cap Im(S)$ but $r\neq\bar{0}$. A contradiction).

Now, $\{r,u\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. 
Then, $S(r)=a$ with $a\in Im(S)$ and $S(u)=0$ because $u\in Ker(S)$
Now (again), take $\beta=\{a,u\}$ a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (is linearly independent. The proof is the same). Then

$$ S(a)=S(S(r))=S(r)=a=1a+0u \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ S(u)=0=0a+0u$$

Therefore $$[S]_{\beta}^{\beta}= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{array} \right) $$